# Page not completely loading

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

I don't have any code to post or screenshots because my site is on a corp network, but I've been having some intermittent issues where the webpages don't completely load on times. What happens is that sometimes, instead of loading an image, it will load the ascii or whatever you might see if you opened it in notepad. then, after reloading, it will put a random icon in the favicon then reloading again will load a random script in text view. after a few reloads the css doesn't load then finally it works.

There are never any error messages (firebug or browser). There is nothing weird in the logs.

I've googled around but can't seem to find the answer, not sure i'm searching in the right place. The website is Java based with JSP pages. We are running on a Tomcat server.

Any ideas why something like this would keep happening?

Comment: Hrm. I'm pretty sure it's a misconfiguration, but I'm not sure what the fix was (or even if it was fixed completely). Just as a off-the-hand thing, check your web.xml and make sure everything is routed properly. The lack of error messages and logging is normal for this though.

Comment: I have the same config on my localhost and the live servers. I've compared them both to the original that came with the apache and they are all identical.